# How to find max value per each 8 row in csv format

Tags: python

I have two colum contained date and value.
I need to find the maximum  value from each 8 row or 8 day.
Cloud anyone suggest me what tool or what library ?

Simple Data

```js
timestamp  value
1/7/2017    0.4422709
2/7/2017    0.47979677
3/7/2017    0.48154536
4/7/2017    0.50247365
5/7/2017    0.45446774
6/7/2017    0.44231474
7/7/2017    0.48774317
8/7/2017    0.48993695
9/7/2017    0.48612505
10/7/2017   0.48970944
11/7/2017   0.46920314
12/7/2017   0.47724804
13/7/2017   0.4656107
14/7/2017   0.47519404
15/7/2017   0.44820467
16/7/2017   0.4583039
17/7/2017   0.44056067
```

Comment: if you have list then you can use indexes `[0:8]`, `[8:16]`, ... `[n:n+8]` to get 8 rows (you could use `for`-loop for this) and later you can make calcuations in selected rows

Comment: always put code, data and full error message as text (not screenshot, not link) in question (not in comment).  It will be more readable and easier to use in answer, and more people will see it - so more people can help you.

Comment: what have you tried till now?

Comment: if you use pandas then probably you could use `groupby` with `index` and function which use `index // 8`. Or maybe `rolling window` with size 8 and step 8

Comment: if would be much simpler if you would put data as `DataFrame(...)` so we could simply copy it and use in solutions. You may even use `random` to generate values.

Comment: I wondering if you mean rows `[0:8]`, `[8:16]` or  `[0:8]`, `[1:9]`, `[2:10]`, etc. (and this is `rolling window`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if you want do it for rows `[0:8]`, `[8:16]` or `[0:8]`, `[1:9]`, `[2:10]`, etc. (which seems more useful for me) and I describe for both versions using `pandas.DataFrame`

I use `io` to simulate file - so everyone can copy and test - but you use `filename` to load file.

```
import pandas as pd
import io

text  ='''timestamp value
1/7/2017    0.4422709
2/7/2017    0.47979677
3/7/2017    0.48154536
4/7/2017    0.50247365
5/7/2017    0.45446774
6/7/2017    0.44231474
7/7/2017    0.48774317
8/7/2017    0.48993695
9/7/2017    0.48612505
10/7/2017   0.48970944
11/7/2017   0.46920314
12/7/2017   0.47724804
13/7/2017   0.4656107
14/7/2017   0.47519404
15/7/2017   0.44820467
16/7/2017   0.4583039
17/7/2017   0.44056067
'''

#df = pd.read_csv('filename')
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(text), sep='\s+')
```

---

If you need rows `[0:8]`, `[8:16]` then you can use

```
df['part'] = df.index // 8
```

to create new column `part`

```
    timestamp     value  part
0    1/7/2017  0.442271     0
1    2/7/2017  0.479797     0
2    3/7/2017  0.481545     0
3    4/7/2017  0.502474     0
4    5/7/2017  0.454468     0
5    6/7/2017  0.442315     0
6    7/7/2017  0.487743     0
7    8/7/2017  0.489937     0
8    9/7/2017  0.486125     1
9   10/7/2017  0.489709     1
10  11/7/2017  0.469203     1
11  12/7/2017  0.477248     1
12  13/7/2017  0.465611     1
13  14/7/2017  0.475194     1
14  15/7/2017  0.448205     1
15  16/7/2017  0.458304     1
16  17/7/2017  0.440561     2
```

and later you can use it to `group` rows and get `max()`

```
result = df.groupby('part')['value'].max()
print(result)
```

result

```
0    0.502474
1    0.489709
2    0.440561
```

You can also do it without creating column `part`

```
result = df.groupby( df.index//8 )['value'].max()
```

---

If you need rows `[0:8]`, `[8:16]` or `[0:8]`, `[1:9]`, `[2:10]`, etc. then you can use `rolling window` with size `8`

```
df['max'] = df['value'].rolling(window=8, min_periods=1).max()
```

and you get

```
    timestamp     value       max
0    1/7/2017  0.442271  0.442271
1    2/7/2017  0.479797  0.479797
2    3/7/2017  0.481545  0.481545
3    4/7/2017  0.502474  0.502474
4    5/7/2017  0.454468  0.502474
5    6/7/2017  0.442315  0.502474
6    7/7/2017  0.487743  0.502474
7    8/7/2017  0.489937  0.502474
8    9/7/2017  0.486125  0.502474
9   10/7/2017  0.489709  0.502474
10  11/7/2017  0.469203  0.502474
11  12/7/2017  0.477248  0.489937
12  13/7/2017  0.465611  0.489937
13  14/7/2017  0.475194  0.489937
14  15/7/2017  0.448205  0.489937
15  16/7/2017  0.458304  0.489709
16  17/7/2017  0.440561  0.489709
```

---

Full code:

```
import pandas as pd
import io

text  ='''timestamp value
1/7/2017    0.4422709
2/7/2017    0.47979677
3/7/2017    0.48154536
4/7/2017    0.50247365
5/7/2017    0.45446774
6/7/2017    0.44231474
7/7/2017    0.48774317
8/7/2017    0.48993695
9/7/2017    0.48612505
10/7/2017   0.48970944
11/7/2017   0.46920314
12/7/2017   0.47724804
13/7/2017   0.4656107
14/7/2017   0.47519404
15/7/2017   0.44820467
16/7/2017   0.4583039
17/7/2017   0.44056067
'''

#df = pd.read_csv('filename')
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(text), sep='\s+')

# --- 1a ---

df['part'] = df.index // 8
result = df.groupby('part')['value'].max()
print(result)

# --- 1b ---

result = df.groupby(df.index//8)['value'].max()
print(result)

# --- 2 ---

df['max'] = df['value'].rolling(window=8, min_periods=1).max()
print(df)
```

Comment: i have try your suggestion and it work. But it work when I copy all my data to the line " text  ='''timestamp value ".
When I 
Could you suggest me more detail how to to config with csv file in the line #df = pd.read_csv('filename', sep='\s+')

Comment: @weraphongsuaruang if you use standard csv with data separated by commas then use without `sep='\s+'`. And put your file name instead `filename`. `pd.read_csv('my_data.csv')`. More options in doc [read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)

Comment: It work when use without  `sep='\s+'`
Thank so much.

Answer (score 0):

```
use simple file operation for finding max values

with open("data.log",'r') as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
    prevValues = []
    for index, line in enumerate(lines):
        if index == 0:
            continue
        cols = line.split(" ")
        prevValues.append(float(cols[1]))
        if index % 8 == 0:#if we have read 8 rows
            print(max(prevValues))
            prevValues.clear()#clearing the list
    if len(prevValues) > 0:
            print(max(prevValues))
```

### Output:

```
0.50247365
0.48970944
0.44056067
```

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

###### You can try this. Just change the file name and the delimeter based off the structure of your csv.

```py
import csv
filename="text.csv"
count = 1
days = 8
maxVal = 0
maxValues=[]
with open(filename,'r') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter=' ')
    for row in reader:
        if count % days == 0:
            maxValues.append(max(float(maxVal),float(row['value'])))
            maxVal = 0
        else:
            maxVal = max(float(maxVal),float(row['value']))
        count+=1
print(maxValues)
```

## Output

```
0.50247365
0.48970944
```